# PHP - value of previous key in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a sql query that is returning me rows like this:

`ID  |  Code | Numb 
 1   |   1   |  1 
 2   |   2   |  2 
 3   |   3   |  3`

and I am trying to write foreach loop that will always show the previous values.

My normal foreach loop like this:

`foreach($array as $key => $val) {
 echo '$val['code'];
}`

how can i make the value to always be from the previous row?

Comment: What's your expected output? The question is not clear as not sure why you would want to do this.

Comment: the loop always with zero, if you want specific value before key, we can get

Comment: my goal is when the loop is echoing the second code which is 2 it should be 1 @LawrenceCherone then the third code will be 2

Comment: Then you should accept @Sohel0415 answer as it does exactly that (though a little untidy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could kept your `old value` to a `variable` and use it at the next `iteration`. And as **@Daniel** notices, you need to check that variable defined or not by using `isset()`.

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
  if(isset($prev)) 
     echo $prev;
  $prev = $val['code'];
}
```

Comment: First time **echo $prev;** is undefined. You should check it **if(isset($prev)) echo $prev;**

Comment: You would have to echo once more outside of the loop for the final item.

Comment: @Matt Yes, If he needs, he should, I just consider the previous data part

Comment: @Sohel0415, I have tried and it worked fine .. thank you